# Convert MySQL blob to base64 and return as JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to decode blob value from MySQL data table and return this by json in php
Why json is empty?

```
  $sth->execute($_REQUEST);
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if(count($result) > 0) 
    {
        $rows = array();
        foreach($result as $r)
        {
              $rows[] = $r;
        }

        foreach($rows as $key=>$value)
        {
          $newArrData[$key] =  $rows[$key];
          $newArrData[$key]['Data'] =base64_encode($rows[$key]['Data']);
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($newArrData);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you copying $results array to $rows array? You can throw away first loop and in second loop you can iterate over  $result array - this can be a first step to solve problem.

Comment: @Coreus your edit removed all the `=` from the code block. Hopefully that wasn't what you had in mind.

Comment: @dmilan22 Can you edit the question the add an example of what you expect the JSON output to look like?

Comment: Also, how many rows are you expecting your query to return? And are you intentionally discarding the first row?